# Xampp Tomcat doesn't start return code: -1073741510

Tags: java, windows, apache, tomcat, xampp

I'm new using Xampp but I have serous trouble finding what's the issue with tomcat is. I've changed ports of `apache (4430, 8080)` and `mysql (3306)`.

I've also changed the port for tomcat from 8080 to 8020, 8082 ... but none of them seem to work. I've always get this message from Control Panel

> Tomcat Started/Stopped with errors,`return code: -1073741510`

```
11:41:02  [Tomcat]  Make sure you have Java JDK or JRE installed and the required ports are free
11:41:02  [Tomcat]  Check the "/xampp/tomcat/logs" folder for more information

Also when I stop the process I've recently get this other message: 

Port 8080 in use by "C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe"!
11:53:38  [Tomcat]  Tomcat WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
11:53:38  [Tomcat]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
11:53:38  [Tomcat]  or reconfigure Tomcat and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

I've also add what the Control panel displays, I'm really confused because I don't know what the problem could be. I've downloaded the last version of JDK and it doesn't work

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMGmd.jpg)

Windows 10 xampp v7

I've also add info about the current status in the server.xml file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJ8xT.jpg)

Comment: your 8080 port is already is in used.. and your `tomcat` port is still unchanged. So please change your port to any other number

Comment: Hi, I've changed the port of the Tomcat as yo can see bellow but it still doesn't work:       <Connector port="8181" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="9090" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->

Comment: Maybe should I change another line?

Answer (score -2):

This is the answer to how to fix this problem.

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]